# rails relationship. Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new in the world of rails developers. Please, help me to understand.
I've 3 tables:
Calls, Questions, Results

Calls is:
id, name, date

**Questions is: 
id,  question**

Results is:
id, call_id, question_id, result

I've read the Rails manual, as i understand i've created 3 models.

In my model Call.rb
I've done next relationship:

```
has_many   :results
has_many   :question, through: :results
```

My Result.rb

```
belongs_to :call
belongs_to :question
```

My Question.rb

```
has_many :result
```

So, there are can be many records in the table "results" with one **call_id**, and it's can be one relation with question through **results** table

If if try to launch code like this:

```
@calls = Call.all
```

Than on my view:

```
<% @calls.each do |call| %>
<%= call.result.result %>
<% end %>
```

i've error that "result is undefined method". But it's must be a property.

What i do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just `<%= call.result %>`?

Comment: but i have no field **call_id** in the table questions.
so, for me has_many :questions - it is also wrong

Comment: if i do <%= call.result %> - i've error:
undefined method `result'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your schema, your associations should look like this

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :results
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :call
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :call
end
```

So in the view,

```
<% @calls.each do |call| %>
  <% call.results.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.result%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so i needed to do 2 cycles, this is solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

First, you need to fix your associations so the plural and singular tenses match. `has_many :result` does not work as Marcelo points out.

Second, you need to ensure that your tables actually have the correct id's to make the associations work. Use the rails console to inspect `Result`. From your question info, it should have attributes for `call_id` and `question_id`. Once you've confirmed this, create a few objects in the console and test your associations.

```
@call = Call.create(name: "test", date: Time.now)

@result = Result.create(call_id: @call.id, result: "some result")
```

Then

```
@call.result # should yield the Result record you just created
```

Lastly, you need to rename the `result` attribute for `Result`. That's super confusing and will only cause problems.

Comment: can u explain me please different with plural and singular?

Comment: `has_many` implies plural (i.e. more than one). So if you're going to use `has_many` it needs to be with `:results` (plural) NOT `result` (singular).

Comment: ah it's very simply, thanks. Now i try to fix and try your solution!

Comment: Vimsha's solutions work for me, thank you for explain!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that your call should have many questions, and many results through questions. That's because calls own questions, which in turn own results themselves.

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :results, through: :questions
end
```

You didn't need call_id in Result class. But, if you wish to keep it there, you dont need through: :questions in your call class (given there is a direct relation between them)

In your Question class, I assume it is a typo, but it should be plural

```
has_many :results
```

Having said that, your loop through calls will bring results (plural) and not result (singular) given that a call may have many results. Therefore:

```
<% @calls.each do |call| %>
  <% call.results.each do |result| %>
    <%= call.result %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, i'v pdated my post, because this is error in schema description

Comment: please, look at new schema description

Comment: @user2051503 please revise again your schema before I update my answer. If you want to use has_many, it must be plural. You need to decide if it is going to be has_many or not. "has_many :result or has_many :question" is wrong.

Comment: All ok with schema. 
one call has many results
and one call has many questions through result<
Thanks